# nested property-read in manifest

Tags: java, xml, ant, nested, manifest

I have the following build.xml code. Here i do modify the manifest file in a jar file. In manifest i wanted to add few attributes such as Asset-Name and Asset-Baseline.

Content of **buildInfo.properties** is as followed:

```
articlelib_componentname=ABC component.
articlelib_baselineName=Baseline_1.
buslib_componentname=XYZ component.
buslib_baselineName=Baseline_2.
```

build.xml:
I want to pass the name i.e articlelib value dynamically, and retrieve the values from buildInfo.properties. I used macrodef outside manifest it's working file but when i use the same in manifest tag I'm unable to use it. Can I have a work around for this problem or alternative solution to pass dynamic values to manifest so that I can retrieve values from the builInfo.properties

```
<property name="name" value="articlelib" />

<property name="name_path" value="${name}_componentName" />
<property file="buildInfo.properties" prefix="buildInfo" />

<property file="buildInfo.properties"/>

    <macrodef name="property-read">
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <attribute name="from"/>
        <sequential>
            <property name="@{name}" value="${@{from}_componentName}"/>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="test">
        <echo>PRODUCT_NAME: ${name}</echo>
        <property-read name="instance" from="${name}"/>
        <echo>DYNAMIC PROPERTY VALUE: ${instance}</echo>
    </target>

<target name="earchive" description="Generate the EAR file">

        <jar destfile="${dir.dist}/${name}.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Specification-Title" value="${name}" />
                <property-read name="instance" from="${name}"/>
                <attribute name="Asset-Component" value="${instance}" />
                <echo>DYNAMIC PROPERTY VALUE: ${instance}</echo>
                <attribute name="Asset-Baseline" value="${buildInfo.articleliblocal.baselineName}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>

    </target>
</project>
```

When i use the above property-read micro in manifest tag i get the following error:

**BUILD FAILED**

H:\Ant_Scripts_Testing\hello.xml:27: manifest doesn't support the nested "proper
    ty-read" element.
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChildren(UnknownElement.jav
    a:359)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChild(UnknownElement.java:5
    69)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChildren(UnknownElement.jav
    a:346)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.configure(UnknownElement.java:198
    )
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.jav
    a:160)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
    cutor.java:41)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
    Caused by: class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Manifest doesn't support the nest
    ed "property-read" element.
            at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper.throwNotSupported(Introspect
    ionHelper.java:447)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChildren(UnknownElement.jav
    a:349)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigned the dynamic value to a new variable outside manisfest and read the same variable in manifest which solved the issue.